# InputIterator for contiguous memory?

Tags: c++, templates, input, iterator

I'm trying to add some debug instrumentation for a vector. My class "has a" vector and offers functions such as:

```
template <typename InputIterator>
  void assign(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
```

Vector and strings are containers with contiguous memory. When `first` and `last` are from a vector (or other container with contiguous memory), I can perform additional sanity checks on the iterators. For example, I can check:

- last > first
- [first, last) don't overlap with existing elements
- count = last - first + 1 is sane

I want to provide a specialization for the additional diagnostics and instrumentation when the container uses contiguous memory, but I don't know what the iterator is called (and have not been able to locate it grepping through sources):

```
template <typename SequentialIterator>
  void assign(SequentialIterator first, SequentialIterator last)
```

What is the name of the 'SequentialIterator' or 'ContiguousIterator'?

Comment: [`std::random_access_iterator_tag`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags)?

Answer (score 3):

You could use tag dispatching and some standard type traits to choose the appropriate implementation of `assign()` based on the category of the iterator.

For instance, this basic solution lets you provide two different implementations for random access iterators and non-random access iterators:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iterator>

struct X
{
    template <typename InputIterator>
    void assign(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
    {
        assign_impl(
            first, last,
            typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::iterator_category()
            );
    }

    template <typename InputIterator>
    void assign_impl(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                     std::random_access_iterator_tag)
    {
        // Implementation for random access iterator...
    }

    template <typename InputIterator>
    void assign_impl(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, 
                     std::input_iterator_tag)
    {
        // Implementation for non-random access iterator...
    }
};
```

Comment: why `is_same` and `bool` rather than just using the actual tag?  Everything I've seen just uses the actual tag.  That's why it's called tag dispatching.  http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=897e78f36e82154b3520dee357ae7f33

Comment: `InputIterator::iterator_category` -- should be --> `std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::iterator_category`

Comment: Thanks Andy. Wouldn't this be pushing a compile time activity into a runtime activity? I would prefer to do it at compile time with the right type if iterator.

Comment: @noloader: In theory, yes. There is some run-time activity, but the call is resolved statically (the compiler knows at compile-time which function to invoke). Therefore, in practice, it is possible that the compiler will see the that constructor of `std::input_iterator_tag` or `std::random_access_iteartor_tag` has no side-effect, and that you are not using the corresponding parameter in the function, so he might remove the construction of that object at all.

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee that the elements of the sequence under a particular iterator are contiguous. There are only guarantees on the operations you can perform with an iterator. There are four main iterator types:

- Random Access
- Bidirectional
- Forward
- Input

They can each (except Input) also satisfy the requirements of an Output Iterator, which makes them mutable iterators.

The closest iterator to what you're asking for is a Random Access Iterator. It supports comparison with `>` and `<` and allows you to add and subtract iterators from each other. You can even use the array subscript operator with them. They give the illusion that the elements are stored contiguously, but there's no guarantee that they really are.

Comment: input iterator doesn't satisfy output iterator.

Comment: "There is no guarantee that the elements of the sequence are contiguous." Are you certain about that? I always though, for example, string was guaranteed to be contiguous. I thought it applied to vector as well. I understand it does not apply to a list. In the case of list, I would have to use the `InputIterator` and forgo the extra instrumentation and diagnostics.

Comment: @noloader There *is* a guarantee that `std::basic_string` and `std::vector` store their elements contiguously. But that's independent of the iterator being used to access them. Of course, storing elements contiguously makes it easier to provide a random access iterator, which is why they do. There's just no guarantee that if you have a Random Access iterator then the data it points at is contiguous.

Comment: Thanks sftrabbit. What's the iterator I should use for containers with contiguous memory? Is it `RandomAccessIterator`? Please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: Just to provide a concrete example: random access iterator, but no contiguous memory: `std::deque`...